# how can I save an isodate field using MongoSpark.save from mongodb spark connector v2.1?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

everyone. A little bit of help would be nice, and I thank you for it. I'm trying to save a document which contains a datetime field. Using mongodbspark connector through MongoSpark.save() method, it could be a challenge:

- if a set the field as a string, it's quite obvious that what will be saved is a string, not an isodate (even if the string fulfilled the ISO 8601 format
- if I build an expression like this: my:date:{$date:}, where xxxx is some epoch time in milliseconds, then I get this BulkWriteError which set that '$' sign is not valid for storage

I get documents to be update from a library which returns BsonDocument docs. Datetime fields are treated like BsonDateTime fields, so I need to make some conversions before saving/updating 'cause getting the corresponding json string fro the BsonDocument, generates the $date non-valid-for-storage stuff.

For obtaind the BsonDocument, I just called a method from a library built by another developer:

```
val bdoc = handlePermanentProduct(p_id, operationsByProduct)
```

Then I convert the org.bson.BsonDocument in a org.bson.Document using a method I wrote:

```
val doc: Document = convert(bdoc)
```

Then, the usual code for getting a dataframe & saving/updating my documents

```
val docs = sc.parallelize(Seq(doc.toJson))
val df = sparkSession.read.json(rdd)
MongoSpark.save(df.write.option("collection", "products").option("replaceDocument", "false").mode(SaveMode.Append))
```

Thanks again, and in advance

I'm using Scala 2.11.8, Spark 2.11, and Mongodb Spark connect v2.1

Answer (score 2):

Definitively, the way I was trying to use for saving/updating is not the right way. I found out, reading the documentation, of course, that there is a type matching process when I want to save/update using ***MongoSpark.save(...)*** method: datetime fields can be creates as **java.sql.Timestamp**, so driver makes the proper conversions. It was really easy once I found that. So, it's solved.